# GAE Random Uncaught Exception Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine

I have a codeigniter app on google app engine and as I move about the application it will mostly work but I'll get these intermittent problems where I'll click on a page and it'll be completely blank with only a title in the HTML that reads:

```
<html><head>
<title>s~nypl-cap : uncaught application failure</title><body><pre><br></pre></body></html>
```

When I check the logs all I get is a 500 error that reads:
 "A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)"

If I refresh the page it reloads just fine.  I have no clue what could be wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Somehow your app is crashing the runtime. Are you using any frameworks? There are known problems with ZF2 which can be fixed for now by disabling APC.

Comment: As I mentioned I'm using Codeigniter framework.  I read on another post about disabling APC, but it didn't work for me.  The error logs are so vague I can't figure out what could be crashing it.  The error message I receive is completely intermittent.  The app I have right now is little more than a hello world app so I can't see what could be crashing it.

Comment: Do you mind to sure the code so we can investigate this issue further? Thanks.

Comment: Not at all. You can pull the source from here: https://github.com/aurena/CodeIgniter_on_GAE 
You can access the app here, you just need to login with a Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

"[App Engine cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections to a Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/#PHP_Managing_connections)". So, you need to close the any established connections before processing a request. If you do not do this it will cause a leak may eventually new connection to fail. And that could be one of the reason why you are getting 204 error. So in your "[database.php](https://github.com/aurena/CodeIgniter_on_GAE/blob/master/application/config/database.php)" file in Production (App Engine Cloud SQL) DB Settings section can you change the line `$db['production']['pconnect'] = TRUE;` to `$db['production']['pconnect'] = FALSE;` and see if it works or not.

Comment: I gave up on using Codeigniter/PHP on GAE months ago.  Decided to go the Python/Ferris route and use NDB.  It's much easier and way less problematic.  Thanks for trying though.